# I can't follow gae tutorial because of 'ascii' codec can't decode error

Tags: google-app-engine

I was following this tutorial.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/appengine

When I tried to follow Section 1-6

"Test this URL in your browser: http:// localhost:8080/rpc?action=Echo¶ms={"example":"blah"}&key=mySecretKey."
(I added a space between "http://" and "localhost" to avoid auto error check of stackover 
flow.)

I could not follow because of this error.

```
<type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 141: ordinal not in range(128) please see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details (backend.py) 
      args = ("'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position...n.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details (backend.py)",) 
      filename = None 
      lineno = None 
      message = "'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position...n.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details (backend.py)" 
      msg = "'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position...n.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details (backend.py)" 
      offset = None 
      print_file_and_line = None 
      text = None
```

Before this tutorial, I've read a "Hello World" tutorial for Google App Engine. And it worked fine.

What should I do to remove the error?

P.S.
In the tutorial I found a typo "Section 1: Using the Script Editor" should be "Section 1: Creating and deploying an App Engine service". I think.

Comment: This question is about app engine, not just apps script. I've retagged your question so people familiar with app engine can help too.

Comment: Thanks to change tag. :)

Comment: Oh, I found now, what was the problem.
because of the character entity reference, all `&para' are replaced with pilcrow signs in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

The pilcrow sign ¶ (in "... `action=Echo¶ms=` ...") has a representation in ascii as B6, but in UTF-8 it is represented as C2 B6.

Your browser or editor is probably (and quite reasonably) using UTF-8 as the encoding for the script. A workaround may be to change your encoding to Western or ascii, then paste the script again.

Comment: Thanks Stephen.
But I could not find the way how to set encoging to Western or ascii by Chrome.
So I deleted the comment lines that include pilcrow sign in script and changed the arguments to "...`action=Echo&params=`...".
Then works it fine.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode problems are very common in GAE python applications. This article from Nick Johnson will help you with your Python code:
http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Getting-unicode-right-in-Python